# Ionic refresher conflicts with hide show animation AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have one page where I wish to use the feature pull to refresh. 
In this page I have 2 hide and show sections.

For some reason, my page refreshes everytime I touch to show what is hidden
in the hide/show toogles.
If I remove the code only on controller. My page still pulls to refresh with just the html code, and it works fine with hide/show but in this case, the page after reload, doesn't really stay on the top but a bit below instead.
How to fix this? Seems like a conflict between ionic and angularjs animation with hide/show

code below:

```
<ion-view has-bouncing="false">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="Loader" class="simpleFadeIn" ng-if="!AccountLoaded">
            <loader-bcs></loader-bcs>
        </div>
        <div style="opacity:0;animation-delay:0.8s" ng-class="AccountLoaded? 'simpleFadeIn':''">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="headerCol"></div>
                <div class="headerCol">
                    <img src="content/images/icon.png" class="iconApp">
                </div>
                <div class="headerCol" ng-click="goToPatrimonyPage()">
                    <i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()" refreshing-icon="" ng-hide="true">
            </ion-refresher>
            <div class="content-container">
                <div class="titlePage">{{'IntegratedPosition' | translate}}</div>
                <div id="contentList">
                    <div class="CardListClose CardList" ng-class="showDetailsActive == true ? '':'CardListClose'" ng-click="showDetailsActive==true ? showDetailsActive=false : showDetailsActive=true">
...
  <div class="CardListClose CardList" ng-class="showDetailsPassive == true ? '':'CardListClose'" ng-click="showDetailsPassive==true ? showDetailsPassive=false : showDetailsPassive=true">
                        <div class="headerCard">
                            <div class="CardHeaderCol"> ....
 </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and on controller:

```
        $scope.doRefresh = function () {
            bcsSQLiteStorage.deleteDataDB(EntityIntegratedPositionKey);
            bcsSQLiteStorage.deleteDataDB(EntityFinancialPositionKey);

//this is a call to a service, should I make it synchronous?
            getEntityFinancialIntegratedPosition();
            $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();

        };
```

this code produces the pull to refresh on toogling the hide/show divs

What is the problem here?